# Position the center of a div to given coordinates on a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, positioning

`var x=200, y=140`

How would I position the center of a div (width & height = 50px) to the above coordinates?

Comment: The values are fixed or everything should be dynamics ?

Comment: Forgot to mention that - the coordinates are dynamic, the width and height are static.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should work:

```
//onload 
$(document).ready(function() {
    var x=200;
    var y=140;
    var div = $("#myDiv");
    var divWidth = div.width() / 2;
    var divHeight = div.height() / 2;
    div.css('left', x - divWidth );
    div.css('top', y - divHeight);
});
```

here is the CSS

```
#myDiv{position:absolute; left:0; width:50px; height:50px; background-color:red;}
```

See it in action here: [http://jsfiddle.net/cgvAB/3//](http://jsfiddle.net/cgvAB/3/)

Comment: my bad totally misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this with pure CSS. Assuming your square div is static at 50px, parent div can have any coordinates:

```
.parent{
    position:relative;
    width:200px;
    height:140px;
}
.child{
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin-top:-25px; /* negative half of div height*/
    margin-left:-25px; /* negative half of div width */
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
}
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/F4RVf/1/

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the rest of the page, you could use absolute positioning (potentially inside of a `position:relative` parent, if those are offsets):

```
<style type="text/css">
    #myDiv {
        position: absolute;
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
        left: 200px;
        top: 140px;
        margin: -150px 0 0 -150px;
    }
</style>
```

If your div is variable height/width, you'd need to do the margin bit with javascript (eg with jQuery):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $myDiv = $('#myDiv');
    $myDiv.css({
        'margin-left': -($myDiv.outerWidth({ 'margin': true }) / 2),
        'margin-top': -($myDiv.outerHeight({ 'margin': true }) / 2)
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="mydiv" style="position: absolute; top:115px; left:175px; width:50px; height:50px;"></div>
```

*in case of dynamic coordinates add the following to event handling javascript function:

```
myDiv = document.getElementById('mydiv');
myDiv.style.top = x - 25 + 'px';
myDiv.style.left = y - 25 + 'px';
```